# function didnt update event value

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my function

```
function showNotificationBar(message) {

    /*set default values*/
    duration = typeof duration !== 'undefined' ? duration : 3000;
    bgColor = typeof bgColor !== 'undefined' ? bgColor : "#CAFFC7";
    txtColor = typeof txtColor !== 'undefined' ? txtColor : "#51A427";
    height = typeof height !== 'undefined' ? height : 40;
    /*create the notification bar div if it doesn't exist*/
    if ($('#notification-bar').size() == 0) {
        var HTMLmessage = "<div class='notification-message' style='text-align:center; line-height: " + height + "px;'> " + message + " </div>";
        $('#header').prepend("<div id='notification-bar' style='display:none; width:100%; height:" + height + "px; background-color: " + bgColor + "; position: fixed; z-index: 100; color: " + txtColor + ";border-bottom: 1px solid " + txtColor + ";'>" + HTMLmessage + "</div>");
    }
    /*animate the bar*/
    $('#notification-bar').slideDown(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#notification-bar').slideUp(function() {});
        }, duration);
    });
}
```

but when i use showNotificationBar("hi") will show hi
and after that when i use showNotificationBar("hi2") it will show hi again
please help me

Comment: What about creating [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Unless those variables are meant to be global I would recommend using `var`

Comment: @gillesc I believe they are, otherwise what is the purpose to check their types?

Answer (score 0):

That probably should be because you're creating the element with the first text. You have to create it empty and set the text everytime:

```
function showNotificationBar(message) {

    /*set default values*/
    duration = typeof duration !== 'undefined' ? duration : 3000;
    bgColor = typeof bgColor !== 'undefined' ? bgColor : "#CAFFC7";
    txtColor = typeof txtColor !== 'undefined' ? txtColor : "#51A427";
    height = typeof height !== 'undefined' ? height : 40;

    /*create the notification bar div if it doesn't exist*/
    if ($('#notification-bar').size() == 0) {
        var HTMLmessage = "<div class='notification-message' style='text-align:center; line-height: " + height + "px;'></div>";
        $('#header').prepend("<div id='notification-bar' style='display:none; width:100%; height:" + height + "px; background-color: " + bgColor + "; position: fixed; z-index: 100; color: " + txtColor + ";border-bottom: 1px solid " + txtColor + ";'>" + HTMLmessage + "</div>");
    }

    /* add/update the text message */
    $(".notification-message").text(message);

    /*animate the bar*/
    $('#notification-bar').slideDown(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#notification-bar').slideUp(function() {});
        }, duration);
    });
}
```

Notice that it creates the `.notification-message` empty, then it adds the text message.